# Strip out EMPTY data elements with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

In my workflow I am importing XML into InDesign. Address info is being captured with up to four separate lines of data. Often lines 3 and 4 are blank but I'm getting extra paragraph returns in my layout because the XML contains EMPTY elements like this: `<HomeAddrLine4 />`

In the past, I used a template to ignore empty elements altogether on each element. But my current workflow applies a template to the whole parent element. Is there a way to ignore single elements within a template without having to rewrite my entire XSLT?

Here's the XSLT template (truncated). Let me know if you need more of the XSLT:

```
 ...
 <xsl:template match="Consultant">
 <consultant><Surname><xsl:value-of select="Surname"/></Surname>
 <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></FirstName>
 <HomeAddrLine1><xsl:value-of select="HomeAddrLine1"/></HomeAddrLine1>
 <HomeAddrLine2><xsl:value-of select="HomeAddrLine2[string-length() != 0]"/></HomeAddrLine2>
 <HomeAddrLine3><xsl:value-of select="HomeAddrLine3[string-length() != 0]"/></HomeAddrLine3>
 <HomeAddrLine4><xsl:value-of select="HomeAddrLine4[string-length() != 0]"/></HomeAddrLine4>
 </consultant>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use an xsl:if on the elements to check for value:

```
<xsl:if test="HomeAddrLine2[. != '']">
<HomeAddrLine2><xsl:value-of select="HomeAddrLine2"/></HomeAddrLine2>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You're creating new elements with the exact same name as the existing elements. (example: `<HomeAddrLine1><xsl:value-of select="HomeAddrLine1"/></HomeAddrLine1>`)

If you're not changing anything, maybe `xsl:copy-of` would be a better choice:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*[starts-with(local-name(),'HomeAddrLine') and string()]"/>
```

Another example that includes `Surname` and `FirstName`:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Surname|FirstName|*[starts-with(local-name(),'HomeAddrLine') and string()]"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:copy-of select="(Surname|FirstName|*[starts-with(local-name(),'HomeAddrLine')])[string()]"/>
```

An example of all children of `Consultant`:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*[string()]"/>
```

Comment: I am calling the original data elements in a different order from the source XML. So whatever makes sense